# Slow MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-performance

I am new to MongoDB and trying to understand why are my queries so slow (30-150 seconds per query!). My database contains about 60 million documents. In my queries, I need to combine parametric and fulltext search. This is the query I am trying to analyze:

```
db.collection.explain("executionStats").find(
    {"property.multi.value_title": "Pearson Education (US)", 
     "pricing.price" : {$gte: 70, $lte: 600}, 
      $text: { $search: "app" }
    }).count()
```

And this is the explain result:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.collection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "property.multi.value_title" : {
                                                "$eq" : "Pearson Education (US)"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "pricing.price" : {
                                                "$lte" : 600
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "pricing.price" : {
                                                "$gte" : 70
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "$text" : {
                                                "$search" : "app",
                                                "$language" : "none",
                                                "$caseSensitive" : false,
                                                "$diacriticSensitive" : false
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                        "pricing.price" : {
                                                                "$lte" : 600
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "pricing.price" : {
                                                                "$gte" : 70
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "property.multi.value_title" : {
                                                                "$eq" : "Pearson Education (US)"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "TEXT",
                                        "indexPrefix" : {

                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "translate.cs.content_text",
                                        "parsedTextQuery" : {
                                                "terms" : [
                                                        "app"
                                                ],
                                                "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                                                "phrases" : [ ],
                                                "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "textIndexVersion" : 3,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                                "stage" : "OR",
                                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                                "_fts" : "text",
                                                                                "_ftsx" : 1
                                                                        },
                                                                        "indexName" : "translate.cs.content_text",
                                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                                        "direction" : "backward",
                                                                        "indexBounds" : {

                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 29794,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 7996,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 15992,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 27400,
                        "works" : 7997,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 7996,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 1220,
                        "restoreState" : 1220,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "nCounted" : 6,
                        "nSkipped" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                        "pricing.price" : {
                                                                "$lte" : 600
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "pricing.price" : {
                                                                "$gte" : 70
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "property.multi.value_title" : {
                                                                "$eq" : "Pearson Education (US)"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "nReturned" : 6,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 27400,
                                "works" : 7997,
                                "advanced" : 6,
                                "needTime" : 7990,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 1220,
                                "restoreState" : 1220,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "docsExamined" : 7996,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 7996,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "TEXT",
                                        "nReturned" : 7996,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 27390,
                                        "works" : 7997,
                                        "advanced" : 7996,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 1220,
                                        "restoreState" : 1220,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "indexPrefix" : {

                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "translate.cs.content_text",
                                        "parsedTextQuery" : {
                                                "terms" : [
                                                        "app"
                                                ],
                                                "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                                                "phrases" : [ ],
                                                "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "textIndexVersion" : 3,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                                                "nReturned" : 7996,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 27390,
                                                "works" : 7997,
                                                "advanced" : 7996,
                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 1220,
                                                "restoreState" : 1220,
                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                "docsRejected" : 0,
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                        "nReturned" : 7996,
                                                        //HERE
                                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 27380,
                                                        "works" : 7997,
                                                        "advanced" : 7996,
                                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                                        "saveState" : 1220,
                                                        "restoreState" : 1220,
                                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                                        "docsExamined" : 7996,
                                                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                                "stage" : "OR",
                                                                "nReturned" : 7996,
                                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 175,
                                                                "works" : 7997,
                                                                "advanced" : 7996,
                                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                                "saveState" : 1220,
                                                                "restoreState" : 1220,
                                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                                "dupsTested" : 7996,
                                                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                        "nReturned" : 7996,
                                                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 165,
                                                                        "works" : 7997,
                                                                        "advanced" : 7996,
                                                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                                                        "saveState" : 1220,
                                                                        "restoreState" : 1220,
                                                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                                "_fts" : "text",
                                                                                "_ftsx" : 1
                                                                        },
                                                                        "indexName" : "translate.cs.content_text",
                                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                                        "direction" : "backward",
                                                                        "indexBounds" : {

                                                                        },
                                                                        "keysExamined" : 7996,
                                                                        "seeks" : 1,
                                                                        "dupsTested" : 7996,
                                                                        "dupsDropped" : 0
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "ubuntu2004",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "4.4.1",
                "gitVersion" : "ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I couldn't specify my language in the text index, because it is not supported my MongoDB.

I was looking at the time estimates at the executionStats part, and I noticed that after the `IXSCAN` and `OR` operations, that took about 170ms each, the time suddenly jumped to `"executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 27380` at the `FETCH` part.

Can someone please explain what does it mean and how can I improve the performance of this query?

**EDIT:** these are indexes on my collection:

```
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "_fts" : "text",
                    "_ftsx" : 1
            },
            "name" : "translate.cs.content_text",
            "default_language" : "none",
            "language_override" : "none",
            "weights" : {
                    "translate.cs.content" : 1
            },
            "textIndexVersion" : 3
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "property" : 1
            },
            "name" : "property_1"
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "property.multi.value_title" : 1
            },
            "name" : "property.multi.value_title_1"
    }
```

Comment: What index do you current have?

Comment: I edited my question and listed the indexes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you either have very slow disk or not enough memory for this workload.

- If you are using a magnetic disk, switch to SSD.
- If you are using network-attached storage (e.g. all of Amazon EBS), improve your network speed (e.g. change to a "High I/O" instance type).
- Give the database more memory.

Look at I/O wait time in `top` to verify the workload is I/O bound.

Comment: I am using a magnetic disk and unfortunatelly I can't switch to a SSD. I just need to make sure that this is the problem - and rule out any other cause for this. I also noticed that the queries only take a long time if I'm using a text search; otherwise it's pretty quick.

Comment: Ok so i downloaded iotop and I can see that the mongod process' I/O wait time is at 70-99% all of the time. Which confirms your theory about a very slow disk I suppose. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a query that ensure *selectivity*. For this you can created a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index). Also is good to mention that you can [specified a language](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#specify-the-default-language-for-a-text-index) in the text index (default is english)

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { 
    property.multi.value_title: 1,
    field: "text",
    pricing.price: 1
 },
   { default_language: "spanish" }
)
```

For compound indexes, [ESR](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) is helpful in deciding the order of fields in the index:

> 1. First, add those fields against which Equality queries are run.
> 2. The next fields to be indexed should reflect the Sort order of the query.
> 3. The last fields represent the Range of data to be accessed.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I couldn't specify my language, because my language (cs) is unfortunately not supported.

Comment: What is the current executionTimeMillis?

Comment: Good solution except every different query shape would need its own index like this, and you can only have one text index per collection.