# Search by text AND value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to find a way how to improve performance of this query:

```
db.collection.find({$text: { $search: "moon" }, "title": "Nadatur", "price" : {$gte: 300, $lte: 800}})
```

By that I mean that I need to:

- perform text search **using the text index** I already have
- filter only the results that also have a particular title and price in the range specified.

The query above works and gives me correct results, but it is very slow. I need to speed it up, is there any better way how to do it? I saw someone mentioning aggregation, but I am not sure if I should use it and how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow MongoDB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941650/slow-mongodb-query)

Comment: No; in those answers it is only suggested to upgrade hardware, however I am trying to find out if there is a way to optimize the query itself.

Comment: Also I cannot use a compound index, because I am using various fields to search by.

Comment: Hi, by various fields you mean, title, price and the one with the text index?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. By that I mean that sometimes I query price, sometimes brand, country of origin, time of creation, or it's something else. Or it's combination of these fields. It really varies from query to query.

Comment: In mi opinion a good alternative is to create a index predicate that fulfill most operations. Lasly if you are usin Atlas you can use the Performance Advisor which monitors queries that took more than 100ms to execute and automatically suggests new indexes to improve performance. Good luck.